# Function strstr only detects the substring in the last line of the text file?

Tags: c

First function inputs the name of the file and the substring one is trying to find in the file

```
void userinput(char filename[],char word[])
{  
  printf("Enter the name of the file\n");
  gets(filename);

  printf("Enter the word\n");
  gets(word);

}
```

Second function reads the file and prints the address of the substring if it is able to find it.

```
 void findandreplace(char filename[], char word[])
 {                                    
   FILE *infile;

  char *ptr1,*ptr2,filearray[1024];
  infile=fopen(filename,"r");

  if(infile==NULL)
  {
    perror("Could not open file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }                                        

 while(fgets(filearray,sizeof(filearray),infile)!=NULL)

 ptr1=filearray;

 if(strstr(filearray,word))
  {
    ptr2=strstr(ptr1,word);
    printf("%p",ptr2);
  } 

 else
  {
    printf("Entered word not found in file");

  }      

}
```

The function strstr is only able to detect the substring in the last line of the file, I do know that fgets leaves a trailing new line character in the buffer, but I am using gets function as the user input, so in this case that is not the reason.

Can someone please let me know why this is happening?

Comment: You do know that `gets` is deprecated, and should never be used because it makes no checks for buffer overflows, right?  The man page for it states that it should never be used.  It only exists for backward compatibility with very old apps.

Comment: It looks like the reason for your problem is that you are reading and discarding all of the file except for the very end, then checking for the presence of the string.  The while loop just reads in blocks of 1024 characters and discards them until it reaches the end.  Then it searches the last chunk that was read.  The assignment to `ptr1` serves no purpose, since it's just going to be an alias for `filearray` (unless the first read fails, in which case it's undefined).

Comment: @TomKarzes `gets` was deprecated between 1999 and 2011. Since 2011 it no longer exists

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this:

```
while(fgets(filearray,sizeof(filearray),infile)!=NULL)

 ptr1=filearray;
```

Your `while` loop has no associated block. It should look like this.

```
while( condition ) {
    code to do for each iteration
}
```

In C, if a loop or if statement has no block, it will use the next statement. So what you wrote above is equivalent to this.

```
while(fgets(filearray,sizeof(filearray),infile)!=NULL) {
   ptr1=filearray;
}
```

You're iterating through every line in the file and assigning them to `ptr1`. At the end of the file loop you have only the last line in `ptr1`. Then the rest of the code runs on just that last line.

Instead you want this.

```
while(fgets(filearray,sizeof(filearray),infile)!=NULL) {
    ptr1=filearray;

    if(strstr(filearray,word))
    {
        ptr2=strstr(ptr1,word);
        printf("%p",ptr2);
    } 

    else
    {
        printf("Entered word not found in file");

    }      
}
```

---

To avoid this sort of problem in the future, be sure to use an editor that automatically indents your code. For example, [Atom](https://atom.io) is a good choice. The indentation will immediately show the problem. Here's what your code looks like after letting Atom auto-indent.

```
while(fgets(filearray,sizeof(filearray),infile)!=NULL)

ptr1=filearray;

if(strstr(filearray,word))
{
    ptr2=strstr(ptr1,word);
    printf("%p",ptr2);
} 

else
{
    printf("Entered word not found in file");

}
```

Note how the following statements are indented the same as the `while` statement. This tells you they're not part of the `while` loop.

In contrast, when I put the block in and auto-indent, you can clearly see which statements are inside the `while` loop.

```
while(fgets(filearray,sizeof(filearray),infile)!=NULL) {
    ptr1=filearray;

    if(strstr(filearray,word))
    {
        ptr2=strstr(ptr1,word);
        printf("%p",ptr2);
    } 

    else
    {
        printf("Entered word not found in file");

    }      
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the conceptual mistake. Basically I am overwriting my first line, with second and second with third and so on? In the end, I am only left with the last line which overwrites second last line, that is what is going on right?

Comment: @AMD Yes. You forgot the braces around the `while` loop, so only `ptr1=filearray` is in the loop. `filearray` and then `ptr1` gets the first line, second, third, up to the last. By the time `if(strstr(filearray,word))` runs, outside the `while` loop, `filearray` and `ptr1` both contain just the last line.